# Google Maps does not support "geo:" intents, any alternative that does?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, offline-map, google-earth

In Android Firefox (or HTML viewer), when you click on such a [Geo URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI) link:

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">Wikimedia Headquarters</a>
```

... you are asked what Map app to use.

- Select Google Earth and it correctly zooms to the right place
- Select Google Maps (or Maverick) and it only opens the app, not taking you to the right place :-(

My goal is to walk to the said place (so the map app should show both the said place, and my current location/direction using GPS/compass).

Unfortunately, Google Earth is not made for this kind of use. It does not "pin" the said place, so you can't be sure where it was exactly. Also, it does not show my own direction.

Any app that does it?

- When opened from a [Geo Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), pins said place.
- Also shows my own location and direction.
- Bonus for offline maps.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but you may try [OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) if it does just that. It has a fully functional free version and a reasonably priced paid version. It's FOSS also, so you could ask for the functionality to be included or you could send a patch yourself. There's also nightly builds available.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/osmand/issues/detail?id=172

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OsmAnd](http://osmand.net/) is an offline navigation app and should support geo intents [since 2011](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/issues/detail?id=172). It has a fully functional free version and a reasonably priced paid version in the Play store. It's FOSS also, so you could ask for the functionality to be improved or you could send a patch yourself if needed. There's also nightly builds available on the project's site.